# How to list files that has been modified after a given date and that are not in a folder list

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, backup, tar

My aim is to create an incremental tar.gz backup for a folder called `/data`.

To do so, I want to get back the list of files that have been modified after last backup. This moment is stored in a file called `lastran.txt`.

I use following command in order to get this list:

```
find /data -newer lastran.txt -not -type d -print 0
```

I pipe the results of this command to an `xargs -0 tar` command.

My problem is that the results of the `find` command contains a set of files that are in one or more folders that I don't want to add to the archive.

I tried the `--except-from` parameter of `tar` with a file I called `folder-exclusion.lst` that contains a list of folders as:

```
/data/backups
/data/cloud
/data/system
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I've not used this option in `tar`, but it appears that your exclusion file should be a list of _patterns_, so that each line should have `/*` on the end, eg `/data/backups/*`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Several options, take one:

1. Check [`rdiff-backup`](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/), you may be reinventing the wheel.
2. Tell `find` to exclude some patterns in the first place. Use `-wholename` like this:

   ```
   find /data -newer lastran.txt -not -type d -not -wholename "/data/backups/*" -not -wholename "/data/cloud/*" -not -wholename "/data/system/*" -print 0
   ```
3. Take your original `find` and filter its output:

   ```
   find /data -newer lastran.txt -not -type d -print 0 | grep -Ezv "^/data/backups/|^/data/cloud/|^/data/system/"
   ```
4. Fix your `folder-exclusion.lst`. My experience with `tar` is limited and I cannot find anything about the `--except-from` option. If you're sure it's the right option then [AFH's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1236474/how-to-list-files-that-has-been-modified-after-a-given-date-and-that-are-not-in#comment1810763_1236474) may be right:

   > it appears that your exclusion file should be a list of *patterns*, so that each line should have `/*` on the end, eg `/data/backups/*`, etc.